# Need to remove numbers with a javascript code step in Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am not a developer but have used Google search and trial and error test scenarios with Zapier for the last few days and have given up on figuring this out myself.  I need help!

I'm using the Run JavaScript code step in Zapier and provided the following details to Input Data.

It says: What input data should we provide to your code (as strings) via an object set to a variable named inputData?

I'm using "street" with a street address example "1402 Spring Garden Rd"

What is the code to use that regardless of the street address provided all the numbers and first space are removed so that the results is "Spring Garden Rd"

Thank you in advance!

```
var street = inputData;
var streetNoNumbers = inputData.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
return streetNoNumbers
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
TypeError: inputData.replace is not a function
```

I've learned that strings are immutable and a new string can be made from manipulating another string but doing this in zapier seems to require a function and creating another var with the calculation generates a ... is not a function.

I've tried to write a function but can't get the output or return to show the proper results either.

I can do the following successfully,

```
var street = inputData
return street
```

1402 Spring Garden Road

I want to include the code that manipulates street to produce the following:

Spring Garden Road

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question!

The key understanding you're missing is that `inputData` is a js object with a `street` property. Before your code is run, we set it up like so:

```js
const inputData = {street: '1402 Spring Garden Rd'}
```

Since `inputData` is an object, it doesn't have a `replace` method (the error you're seeing). Instead, perform your operation on `.street` and return that.

Try the following:

```js
// need to return an object, not just a string
return {streetNoNumbers: inputData.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')}
```

If you want to learn more, I recommend our simple examples: https://zapier.com/help/code/#simple-email-extraction